# fatal error: Index out of range (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, indexing

Below is my code in the editor for hackerrank. Im getting a fatoal error index out of range in the language swift. I have similar code on my playground, but instead of taking a readLine im just getting a random number to fill my 2D array. This is working on my playground

//hackerrank
https://ghostbin.com/paste/jtc5k

//xcode where it works 
https://ghostbin.com/paste/xqqh4

Comment: Just follow the debug informations, you'll know which index and which array is having  a problem

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ReadLine()` in `playground` file.
[See this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37057)

So your line: `if let input = readLine(),value = Int(input)` doesn't execute therefore your second dimension of array doesn't get fill.

You can change your code to be look like this to see the difference:

```
if let input = readLine(),value = Int(input)
{
    array[row].append(value)
} else {
    array[row].append(Int(arc4random_uniform(2)))
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Read your comment and figured it out.