# User input within while loop before continuing with while loop execution

Tags: swift, while-loop

I'm building a betting loop with a human and computer players in Swift. I essentially have the code structured as follows:

```
let ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var x = 1

while x < 35 {
    for i in ls {
        if i == 1 {
            x += 1
        }
        if i == 2 {
            x += 1
        }
        if i == 3 {
            x += 1
        }
        if i == 4 {
            // ask user how much to increment by
            print("Enter the amount to increment by:")
            if let input = readLine(), let increment = Int(input) {
                x += increment
            } else {
                print("Invalid input")
            }
        }
        if i == 5 {
            x += 1
        }
    }
}
```

The while loop doesn't pause to wait for a user input before carrying on with the rest of the loop. I've tried creating a Thread and using semaphores but have had no luck. What is the "proper" way to achieve this type of goal?

Comment: `readLine()` *does* wait for user input.

Comment: that's why im confused. It's not waiting when run in the application nor in a closed playground environment. It just skips getting the input each time i == 4 and moves on to i == 5 and then repeats the loop until x = 35. nothing I've found has been able to help identify why this is happening

Comment: So you are using a Playground? That does not work. Make a Command Line Application in Xcode.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/37936292/1187415

Comment: thanks. didn't realize playgrounds doesn't take user input. that did the trick as far as testing the simplified code. In my iphone app i seem to be getting a similar proble. The while loop should wait for a user to press a button and enter input before carrying on but it just skips over waiting for the user input. Any ideas on that? I thought testing a simplified version in Playgrounds would help but given the above, I'm not comparing apples to apples.

Comment: iPhone apps are a complete different story. You cannot use readLine() and you cannot “wait” synchronously for input. I don't know what you tried, but generally you use either UIKit (with text fields and delegate functions which are called on certain events) or SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a loop just for the readLine logic so the outer loop will not continue until a correct value has been entered

```
if i == 4 {
    print("Enter the amount to increment by:")
    while let input = readLine() {
        if let increment = Int(input) {
            x += increment
            break
        } else {
            print("Invalid input")
        }
    }
}
```